# Animation complete - Android?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm making use of the following code to flip my ViewFlipper

```
viewFlipper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) { 
                                // This is all you need to do to 3D flip
                                AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewFlipper, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
                        }

        });
```

How do I attach a listener once flipTransition is completed? Any pointers??

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Animation from the flipperView like this.

```
imageViewFlipper.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                      //your code after animation end
                  }
               });
```

Tested and working for me

Comment: Should I attach this animation listener for ViewFlipper?? or the imageview inside ViewFlipper?

Comment: Yes you have to register the ViewFlipper listner

Answer (score 0):

Use `setAnimationListener()`
This will help you to get 3 methods i.e

```
              public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
              public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) 
              public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
```

Make your code accordingly.

in 
`onAnimationStart()`- Write the code which you want to perform when Animation Starts

```
 onAnimationRepeat() - Write you want to be performed when the animation repeats.

onAnimationEnd(){
```

Write what you want to perform when animation ends

```
}
```